# Read csv file from url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to read url but they give me error that `URL must be a string` is there any possible solution for that kindly recommend me how to make the URL string kindly suggest any method

```
from selenium import webdriver           
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import requests
from csv import writer


with open("data.csv") as file:
    start_urls=[line.strip() for line in file]  

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

    driver.get(start_urls)
```

Comment: you need to iterate through your start_urls list, and provide start_urls[i] in driver.get()

Comment: like that `driver.get(start_urls[i])`

Comment: yes, have provided an answer as well. both answers should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by [@JeJe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536343/je-je),

> you need to iterate through your start_urls list

`start_urls` is a LIST of strings, and `driver.get` expects just *one* url as string - something like

```py
# driver.get(start_urls) # NOT like this
for sUrl in start_urls:
    driver.get(sUrl)
    ### SCRAPE AS NEEDED ###
```

or, if you want to keep track of progress, something like

```py
suLen = len(start_urls)
for si, sUrl in enumerate(start_urls):
    print(f'[{si} of {suLen}] reading {sUrl}')
    driver.get(sUrl)
    ### SCRAPE AS NEEDED ###
```

---

Btw, you don't need to do everything under `with open...` - getting `start_urls` is enough:

```py
with open("data.csv") as file:
    start_urls=[line.strip() for line in file]  

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

suLen = len(start_urls)
for si, sUrl in enumerate(start_urls):
    print(f'[{si} of {suLen}] reading {sUrl}')
    driver.get(sUrl)
    ### SCRAPE AS NEEDED ###
```

but you can only use just `start_urls=[line.strip() for line in file]` if you csv has only on column with no headers.

Answer (score 0):

you could rewrite your code using functions to deal with each step of your code.

```
def read_file(has_header:bool=True):
    with open("data.csv") as file:
        start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]

    # assumes there is a header
    if has_header:
        return start_urls[1:]
    else:
        return start_urls

def scrap_urls():
    urls = read_file(has_header=True)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

    for url in urls:
        driver.get(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    scrap_urls()
```